# Need a MySQL query to find the second highest salary for each month from two given tables

Tags: mysql

[The first two tables are the input schema, and the third table is the expected output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek35c.jpg)

EMPLOYEE

| EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | DATE_OF_JOIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMP1 | First Name1 | Last Name1 | 28-3-2011 |
| EMP2 | First Name2 | Last Name2 | 29-3-2021 |
| EMP3 | First Name3 | Last Name3 | 15-3-2022 |

EMPLOYEE_SALARY

| SALARY_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | SALARY_DATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | EMP1 | 30-11-2023 | 100000 |
| 1002 | EMP2 | 30-11-2023 | 45000 |
| 1003 | EMP3 | 30-11-2023 | 50000 |
| 1004 | EMP1 | 30-10-2023 | 100000 |
| 1005 | EMP2 | 30-10-2023 | 45000 |
| 1006 | EMP3 | 30-10-2023 | 30000 |
| 1007 | EMP1 | 30-09-2023 | 100000 |
| 1008 | EMP2 | 30-09-2023 | 45000 |
| 1008 | EMP3 | 30-09-2023 | 30000 |

Desired result

| EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | DATE_OF_JOIN | SALARY_DATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMP2 | First Name2 | Last Name2 | 29-3-2021 | 30-10-2023 | 45000 |
| EMP3 | First Name3 | Last Name3 | 15-3-2022 | 30-11-2023 | 50000 |

The query must achieve the following:
Write a query to find which employee had the second highest salary for the months October and November.

This is the query I came up with:

```
select e.empid, e.firstname, e.lastname, e.dateofjoin, 
s.datesal, max(s.sal) from employee as e
natural join
employee_salary as s
where s.datesal = '2023-11-30' and s.sal not in (select max(sal) 
from employee_salary)
group by e.empid
union 
select e.empid, e.firstname, e.lastname, e.dateofjoin, 
s.datesal, max(s.sal) from employee as e
natural join
employee_salary as s
where s.datesal = '2023-10-30' and s.sal not in (select max(sal)
from employee_salary)
group by e.empid;
```

However, this is the result I get:
[even though its max(sal), I get two values for each month??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akP2O.png)

Comment: Hint - use Window Functions.

Comment: Use ``dense_rank()over(partition by salary_date order by amount desc) as salary_rank``  and then ``salary_rank=2``

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
select e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.date_of_join
   ,s.salary_date ,s.amount
from (
   select * 
    ,dense_rank()over(partition by salary_date order by amount) rnk
   from Employee_Salary
  ) s
left join Employee as e on e.Employee_id=s.Employee_id
where rnk=2
```